# Why is my opengl triangle code producing a black screen?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glfw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }


    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = true;
    glewInit();


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
        glEnd();


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Despite setting glClearColor, only a black screen is shown. Drawing the triangle doesn't work either, and glGetError returns 0 everywhere. What am I doing wrong?

(I know this is a legacy way to render a triangle, I'm just trying to test if opengl is working, and apparently, it isn't.)

Comment: You cannot  use the legacy OpenGL (`glBegin`/`glEnd` sequencise) with a Core profile context (`GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`) you must use  a Compatibility profile context (`GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot  use the legacy OpenGL (`glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences) with a Core profile [`OpenGL Context`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) (`GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`) you must use a Compatibility profile OpenGL context (`GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE`):

<s>`glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);`</s>

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
```

Comment: This didn't work. Plus, glClearColor isn't working either, even without glBegin/glEnd

Comment: @pale_rider What is not working? Do you use a Mac?

Comment: It's still a black screen with no errors. And I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: @pale_rider I can't see any other problem in your code. The problem isn't with your code, it's with your system. Try to update the graphics driver.

Comment: I was afraid of this. I have the latest open source drivers for amd, and there doesn't seem to be a proprietary version for Ubuntu 21.10, which is what I'm on. Oh well.

Comment: @pale_rider [The Mesa 3D Graphics Library](https://www.mesa3d.org/), [How to update mesa drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354219/how-to-update-mesa-drivers)